# Changing DIV height on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on the functionality of my page and ease of use has been one thing i've been targeting. To improve my layout, i've decided to create collapsable sections. However, i'm having 2 problems. 1) I can set the DIV to expand, but not to shrink again. So i decided to create something which tells it if it is larger than the smallest size, expand the content, however now it doesn't expand either. Here is my code:

```
$(".contentBox").click(function(){
    var boxHeight = $(this).height();
    var minBoxHeight = 40;

    if (boxHeight < minBoxHeight)(function() {
        $(this).css({
            height: 'auto',
            transition: 'height 800ms, background 800ms, box-shadow 800ms'
        });
    )};
});
```

2) Because i'm using auto height, which is one way of doing things, i'm sacrificing my animation of sliding when it expands and collapses. However, if anyone knows a way to keep the height changing to the content size aswell as maintaining the animation i want that would be brilliant.

Comment: How is this a ColdFusion question? Shouldn't it be tagged as "jquery" or "javascript"?

Comment: My bad, it's because i'm using coldfusion. I'll change the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
$(".contentBox").click(function(){
        var boxHeight = $(this).height();
        var minBoxHeight = 40;

        if (boxHeight <= minBoxHeight) {
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
            var tmp_height = $(this).height();
            $(this).css('height', boxHeight+'px');
            $(this).css({
                height : tmp_height+'px',
                transition: 'height 800ms, background 800ms, box-shadow 800ms'
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                height: '40px',
                transition: 'height 800ms, background 800ms, box-shadow 800ms'
            });
        }
    });
```

That would let it expand and collapse

I believe this would do all the tricks.
You calculate the height of the div with contents into a variable.
Reset it to it's original position. Then do the transition.

Here's a jsfiddle. I couldn't get it to work with the transition, but got it working with animate:

http://jsfiddle.net/uLabL/

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Only issue is the sliding down transition is absent but on collapsing it re-appears so i'm sure slight tweaking will solve this problem. Thank you again :)

Comment: You're welcome! Check the jsfiddle link. Try experimenting with that ;)

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, simply changed .css to .animate where you had on the jsfiddle and now it does everything i need! I only use this site as a last resort as i'm trying to self tutor, so thanks again!